# Run a container with access to a device without running it as root

Tags: linux, docker, container

I want to run a `zigbee2mqtt` container.

I need to bind a device to the container doing :

```
devices:
  - "/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Texas_Instruments_\
TI_CC2531_USB_CDC___0X00124B00194AD935-if00:/dev/ttyUSB0"
```

And I wand to launch as another user like :

```
user: "${DOCKER_UID}:${DOCKER_GID}"
```

But it hangs with an error I presume its right access (no error when I don't specify user).
There is the error log :

```
  zigbee2mqtt:info 10/27/2019, 5:18:17 PM Logging to directory: '/app/data/log/2019-10-27.17-18-17'
  zigbee2mqtt:info 10/27/2019, 5:18:18 PM Starting zigbee2mqtt version 1.6.0 (commit #e26ad2a)
  zigbee2mqtt:info 10/27/2019, 5:18:18 PM Starting zigbee-shepherd
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Port is not open
    at SerialPort.close (/app/node_modules/zigbee-herdsman/node_modules/@serialport/stream/stream.js:425:29)
    at Znp.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/zigbee-herdsman/dist/znp/znp.js:107:37)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /app/node_modules/zigbee-herdsman/dist/znp/znp.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/app/node_modules/zigbee-herdsman/dist/znp/znp.js:3:12)
    at SerialPort.serialPort.open (/app/node_modules/zigbee-herdsman/dist/znp/znp.js:103:45)
    at SerialPort._error (/app/node_modules/zigbee-herdsman/node_modules/@serialport/stream/stream.js:197:14)
    at binding.open.then.err (/app/node_modules/zigbee-herdsman/node_modules/@serialport/stream/stream.js:241:12)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at SerialPort.onerror (_stream_readable.js:690:12)
    at SerialPort.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at SerialPort._error (/app/node_modules/zigbee-herdsman/node_modules/@serialport/stream/stream.js:199:10)
    at process.nextTick (/app/node_modules/zigbee-herdsman/node_modules/@serialport/stream/stream.js:204:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! zigbee2mqtt@1.6.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the zigbee2mqtt@1.6.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

What's the options/best way to solve this ?
*I don't see any security issue giving a user full rights to this CC2531 (Zigbee receiver)*

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember if/how to do user mapping in docker. However I would just use file permissions: add a new group (`zigbee_device`) to the host, set permission on the device so that users in this group can read and write. Then have the container run with it as one of its groups.